# How to Hangup a call in Asterisk AMI

Tags: python, asterisk

Hello I'm using Python Asterisk to work on my asterisk server. I have been able to listen to current calls using the following code.

```
     def handle_event(event, manager):
     with ctx:

        if event.name == 'CoreShowChannel':
            user_id = event.message['AccountCode']
            user_id = int(user_id)
            data = {
            "channel":event.message['Channel'],
            "channel_state":event.message['ChannelStateDesc'],
            "duration":event.message['Duration'],
            'extension': event.message['Exten'],
            'line': event.message['ConnectedLineNum'],
            'user_id': user_id,
            'context': event.message['Context'],
            'caller_id': event.message['CallerIDNum']
            }

            system = System()
            user = system.getUserById(user_id)
            if user:
                profile = {"first_name":user.first_name,    "last_name":user.last_name}

            data.update(profile)
            g.channels.append(data)
        if event.name == 'CoreShowChannelsComplete':
            g.complete = True
    @app.route('/live-calls')
    def live_calls():
        g.complete = False
        g.channels = []
        manager = asterisk.manager.Manager()
        manager.connect(hostname)
        manager.login(username, secret)
        manager.register_event('*', handle_event)
        res = manager.send_action({'Action':'CoreShowChannels'})

        while not g.complete:

            time.sleep(0.1)
            manager.close()
            if len(g.channels) < 1:
                return json.dumps({"response":g.complete})
            return json.dumps(g.channels)
```

This code serves it purpose and works as expected, now how do I accomplish a hangup method where when I click a hangup button, the current call hangs up. The problem is I know there is an Hangup event but I do not even know the object or variables to check or where to listen to.

Answer (score 0):

I just called the hangup method which takes the channel name as an argument.

I didn't know there is method for that

manager.hangup(channel)

Answer (score -2):

You have to send command to AMI. You can list commands and their parameters in Asterisk CLI

```
pbx*CLI> manager show commands
  Action                          Synopsis
  ------                          --------
  AbsoluteTimeout                 Set absolute timeout.
  AGI                             Add an AGI command to execute by Async AGI.
  AOCMessage                      Generate an Advice of Charge message on a chan
  Atxfer                          Attended transfer.
  BlindTransfer                   Blind transfer channel(s) to the given destina
  Bridge                          Bridge two channels already in the PBX.
  BridgeDestroy                   Destroy a bridge.
  BridgeInfo                      Get information about a bridge.
  BridgeKick                      Kick a channel from a bridge.
  BridgeList                      Get a list of bridges in the system.
  BridgeTechnologyList            List available bridging technologies and their
  BridgeTechnologySuspend         Suspend a bridging technology.
  BridgeTechnologyUnsuspend       Unsuspend a bridging technology.
(...)

pbx*CLI> manager show command Hangup 
[Syntax]
Action: Hangup
[ActionID:] <value>
Channel: <value>
[Cause:] <value>

[Synopsis]
Hangup channel. 

[Description]
Hangup a channel.

[Arguments]
ActionID
    ActionID for this transaction. Will be returned.
Channel
    The exact channel name to be hungup, or to use a regular expression,
    set this parameter to: /regex/
    Example exact channel: SIP/provider-0000012a
    Example regular expression: /^SIP/provider-.*$/
Cause
    Numeric hangup cause.

[See Also]
Not available

[Privilege]
system,call,all

[List Responses]
None

[Final Response]
None
```

Comment: Now the Asterisk AMI has been working and suddenly it stops working yesterday. I don't know what went wrong but I noticed it is taking a lot of time to connect and eventually gives a 502 bad gateway